# Java Canvas size issue

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I'm new to Java ( I have wide knowledge in JavaScript though),

I'm trying to work with `Canvas`, which leads to this weird problem.

As you can see, After I define the size of the `Canvas`, I am trying to print it.
But it doesn't print the size properly.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class test extends Canvas {
    public static final int WIDTH = 180;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    public test() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));

        System.out.println(getWidth());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }
}
```

Why the size is changed ?

Comment: When your dimensions are the same all the time, you can just create a single new Dimension object and pass it to each of these methods. You could even declare it static final and use it in place of the WIDTH and HEIGHT constants.

Comment: I have another question, it's better to ask it now than open a new one.

Comment: *"it's better to ask it now than open a new one."*   Not it is not.  The site (and the search engine for it) is designed around the concept of one question per thread.  As an aside, add @RomanC (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) I suspect the width will keep showing `0` until the component is realized on-screen. 3) Don't use AWT in this millennium.  Use Swing.

Answer (score 5):

> Why it prints zero?? how can I print the size of the canvas properly?

You have not set the size, therefore the width and the height are still 0. You have only set the sizes for the layout hints. These are used by layout managers to lay out the components. Since you are not using a layout manager, the actual size of the canvas is not set.

Use `setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));` to set the actual size.

Comment: @IsraelG. In this case, it might be better to ask a new question, to keep the context between question and answers consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this: `setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))`;

Answer (score 0):

To print it maybe try: System.out.print(test.getWidth())
or: System.out.print(WIDTH)?
sorry i havent really used the java.awt very much but i hope the first one works!